# How to check if a tree of Objects is a BST?

Tags: java, tree, binary-search-tree

I have been working on an isBST method that checks if the Tree of ints is a Binary Search Tree. Now I am trying to create a isBST method that implements Comparable and checks if a tree of Objects is a binary search tree.

What do I have to do to make my isBST method work for objects?

here is my implementation for my isBST method that only works for int Trees.

```
public boolean isBST(TreeNode root, int max, int min) {
    if (root == null) {
        return true;
    } else if (root.data >= max || root.data <= min) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return isBST(root.left, root.data, min) && isBST(root.right, max, root.data);
    }

}
```

I know my header is going to have to be this

```
public <T extends Comparable<? super T>> boolean isBST(BinaryTreeNode<T> root) {

}
```

Comment: The objects will have to have a comparison defined, the `Comparable` interface is fine for this. Then you just use `.compareTo()` instead of `>=`.

Comment: Yea but then what about max and min. They have to be objects

Comment: Im used to only using int's now that I'm trying to branch out it gets more complicated

Comment: Why is `max` and `min` being objects a problem?